# poor 2d performance with nvidia 375.66 and 378.13 (when scrolling, moving windows, watching movies etc.)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, performance, 2d

I completely remove Windows 10 and start using Ubuntu 16.04 lts on my laptop (asus u30sd) but now I experiencing  strange issue and for me serious problem with graphics.
With x.org driver everything was fine with youtube videos, movies and graphic in generela except 3d games (dota max 15fps) so I change driver to nvidia 375.66 and now dota works great (30 - 50 fps) but now with 2d graphic its really annoying. Fast moving windows, fast scenes in movies on yt videos it looks like that something is wrong with refresh rate (choppy videos). I try with 378.13 but its the same.

I am ubuntu rookie, but I also need help in order to solve this issue. Is it possible to have good 2d and 3d performance in the same time? For me this is important topic, if cannot be solved I will come back to windows, but I would really try to fix this with your help.
br,
Marko

Comment: Run this command, does it show as installed? `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04`

Comment: I get this response `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.2
  Candidate: 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.2 500
        500 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1~16.04.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
`

Comment: You could benefit from enabling Prime Synchronization, I've outlined how to do in this post. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449&p=13663158#post13663158 If you don't know how to use nano  ask first. (pretty easy

Comment: In your current case you'd use 378 in the line..

Comment: Hi @doug i will try this prime synchronization tip. Please note that i reverted back nvidia driver to version 375.66 beacouse of some bugs which appears after hibernation. Ty

Comment: I see that you have a thread @ Ubuntu forum, post back there if needing any additional help implementing this

Comment: doug you save me and also my ubuntu "carrier" :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, if you want you can answer your own question & accept that answer. That'll give you a few 'points'

Answer (score 0):

This solve the issue: 
You could benefit from enabling Prime Synchronization, I've outlined how to do in this post. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449&p=13663158#post13663158 If you don't know how to use nano ask first. (pretty easy – doug 8 hours ago

Ty Doug